# Sharing a txpostgres connection pool

Tags: python, postgresql, twisted, psycopg2

We have a RESTful(-ish) twisted application that uses txpostgres to access a postgres db. Currently, we generate new `txpostgres.Connection` instances every time a client pings the server for a db call. This is inefficient and results in our db quickly getting overwhelmed. I've been trying to adapt this to use `txpostgres.ConnectionPool` instead, but am running into trouble. Right now I have something that looks like this:

```
class DBTester(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cfg = load_config('local')  # load the db settings from a JSON file
        self.pool = ConnectionPool(None, min=1, **self.cfg) # create the pool

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get_pool(self):
        yield self.pool.start()
        defer.returnValue(self.pool)


class DBT(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = DBTester()

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def t(self):
        conn = yield self.db.get_pool()
        res = yield conn.runQuery('select * from clients')
        println('DBT.t result: {}'.format(res))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dbt = DBT()
    dbt.t()
    dbt.t()

    reactor.run()
```

The issue is the timing of the `pool.start()` call. If I put it in `DBTester.__init__`, I get `psycopg2.OperationalError: asynchronous connection attempt underway`. If I put it in `DBTester.get_pool`, one `db.t()` call works, and the other(s) fail with `exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'runQuery'`. I've been struggling with this basically all day, and haven't been able to crack it, nor have I been able to find much online.

I really just need a pointer to some minimal example of how `ConnectionPool` is used. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have the pool in the DBTester class? Is there a reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as best practices, but here's what we're going with:

```
## dbutil.py
class DBConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, cfg_name):
        self.cfg_name = cfg_name
        self.cfg = self.load_config(self.cfg_name)
        self.pool = txpostgres.ConnectionPool(None, min=5, **self.cfg)

    @staticmethod
    def load_config(name):
        with open('config.json') as json_file:
            cfg = json.load(json_file)
        return cfg.get(name)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def get_pool(self):
        try:
            yield self.pool.start()
        except txpostgres.AlreadyConnected:
            pass
        defer.returnValue(self.pool)


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def db_factory(cfg_name):
    db = DBConnection(cfg_name)
    db.pool = yield db.get_pool()
    defer.returnValue(db)


## basehandler.py
def __init__(self, name=None, db=None):
    resource.Resource.__init__(self)
    self.name = name
    self.db = db
    self.pool = self.db.pool

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def runQuery(self, *args, **kwargs):
    res = yield self.pool.runQuery(*args, **kwargs)
    defer.returnValue(res)


## server.py
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def init_site(db):
    db = yield db_factory(db)
    root = RootURLHandler(db)
    reactor.listenTCP(SERVER_PORT, site)

def main(db):
    log.startLogging(LogFile('server.log', '.', maxRotatedFiles=5))
    init_site(db)
    reactor.run()
```

The key, perhaps unsurprisingly, was making site initialization a deferred contingent upon the db stuff going through.

Comment: I really think you should reconsider. parts of this code is horrible, sorry to say, especially the `except txpostgres.AlreadyConnected` part. but yeah it works. But it would never go through QA where i work..

Comment: This was pre-QA code--nobody had answered my question and I had gotten an MVP, so I thought I'd do the right thing and share what I'd learned on my own.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your problem is not with txpostgres but more with twisted and the async way of thinking.

**exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'runQuery' means:**
You tried to throw SQL queries after the database before a connection was made. That is stupid! So now I think I will throw an exception so dear User knows about this madness.

So, this could happen if you had something like

```
pool = ConnectionPool(None, min=1)
d1 = pool.start()
d2 = pool.runQuery('select tablename from pg_tables')
```

This code creates two deferreds and thorws em in the reactor. Only the scheduling algorithm knows which one of the two that is executed first, and if it is `d2`, then the error happens.

**txpostgres.txpostgres.AlreadyConnected** means:
Pretty self explaining, it makes no sense to start a pool that is already started.

**psycopg2.OperationalError: asynchronous connection attempt underway means:**
I was in the middle of setting up a nice async database connection when you started executing SQL statements. The database connection was not ready yet and thus the sql queries were not executed    That makes me sad. I think I will throw an operational error so dear User knows that the statement failed.

Okay, so we need a way make sure that the connection is established before we throw sql queries after the database. Below is a code example that uses callbacks to achieve this.

```
from txpostgres.txpostgres import ConnectionPool
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from twisted.python import log, util


class SomeClass(object):

    pool = ConnectionPool(
        None,
        min=1,
        user="user",
        password="pass",
        host='host.com')

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def fetch_tables(self):
        res = yield self.pool.runQuery('select tablename from pg_tables')
        defer.returnValue(res)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def querydb(n=10):
        dl = []
        for i in range(n):
            d = s.fetch_tables()
            d.addCallback(lambda tables: util.println(len(tables)))
            dl.append(d)
        return defer.DeferredList(dl)

    s = SomeClass()
    d_startpool = s.pool.start()
    d_startpool.addCallback(lambda _: querydb())
    d_startpool.addCallback(lambda _: s.pool.close())
    d_startpool.addErrback(log.err)
    d_startpool.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

    reactor.run()
```

Hope this helps.